# Resetting \parskip to 0pt "seems" to be ignored by \par

Tags: paragraphs, lengths

I was revisiting old code and rewriting things in what I thought was a more elegant manner, but I got unexpected results.

I have the following code which seems to do exactly what I want it to do regardless of how I've set the value of `\parskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\ae@tpd{}

\newcommand\savetopreviousdepth{%%
  \par\xdef\ae@tpd{\the\prevdepth}}

\newcommand\restoretopreviousdepth{%%
  \par\prevdepth\ae@tpd
  \ifdim\parskip=0pt
  \else
    \vskip -\parskip
  \fi}

\makeatother

%\setlength\parskip{2ex}

\begin{document}

Horum omnium fortissimi sunt Belgae, propterea quod a cultu atque
humanitate provinciae longissime absunt, minimeque ad eos mercatores saepe
commeant atque ea quae ad effeminandos animos pertinent important,
proximique sunt Germanis, qui trans Rhenum incolunt, quibuscum continenter
bellum gerunt. Qua de causa Helvetii quoque reliquos Gallos virtute
praecedunt, quod fere cotidianis proeliis cum Germanis contendunt, cum aut
suis finibus eos prohibent aut ipsi in eorum finibus bellum gerunt.
\begin{minipage}[t]{4.15in}%%'
  Apud Helvetios longe nobilissimus fuit et ditissimus Orgetorix. Is
  M. Messala, [et P.] M. Pisone consulibus regni cupiditate inductus
  coniurationem nobilitatis fecit et civitati persuasit ut de finibus suis cum
  omnibus copiis exirent: perfacile esse, cum virtute omnibus praestarent,
  totius Galliae imperio potiri. Id hoc facilius iis persuasit, quod undique
  loci natura Helvetii continentur:  una ex parte flumine Rheno latissimo atque
  altissimo, qui agrum Helvetium a Germanis dividit; altera ex parte monte Iura
  altissimo, qui est inter Sequanos et Helvetios; tertia lacu Lemanno et flumine
  Rhodano, qui provinciam nostram ab Helvetiis dividit. His rebus fiebat ut et
  minus late vagarentur et minus facile finitimis bellum inferre possent; qua ex
  parte homines bellandi cupidi magno dolore adficiebantur. Pro multitudine
  autem hominum et pro gloria belli atque fortitudinis angustos se fines habere
  arbitrabantur, qui in longitudinem milia passuum 
  \savetopreviousdepth  
\end{minipage}%%'
\restoretopreviousdepth\noindent
His rebus adducti et auctoritate Orgetorigis permoti constituerunt ea
quae ad proficiscendum pertinerent comparare, iumentorum et carrorum quam
maximum numerum coemere, sementes quam maximas facere, ut in itinere copia
frumenti suppeteret, cum proximis civitatibus pacem et amicitiam
confirmare. Ad eas res conficiendas biennium sibi satis esse duxerunt; in
tertium annum profectionem lege confirmant. Ad eas res conficiendas
Orgetorix deligitur. Is sibi legationem ad civitates suscipit. In eo
itinere persuadet Castico, Catamantaloedis filio, Sequano, cuius pater
regnum in Sequanis multos annos obtinuerat et a senatu populi Romani
amicus appellatus erat, ut regnum in civitate sua occuparet, quod pater
ante habuerit; itemque Dumnorigi Haeduo, fratri Diviciaci, qui eo tempore
principatum in civitate obtinebat ac maxime plebi acceptus erat, ut idem
conaretur persuadet eique filiam suam in matrimonium dat. Perfacile factu
esse illis probat conata perficere, propterea quod ipse suae civitatis
imperium obtenturus esset: non esse dubium quin totius Galliae plurimum
Helvetii possent; se suis copiis suoque exercitu illis regna conciliaturum
confirmat. 

Hac oratione adducti inter se fidem et ius iurandum dant et
regno occupato per tres potentissimos ac firmissimos populos totius
Galliae sese potiri posse sperant.

\end{document}
```

But I thought I could come up with a more elegant solution by rewriting `\restoretopreviousdepth` as

```
\newcommand\restoretopreviousdepth{%%
  \bgroup
    \parskip0pt 
    \par\prevdepth\ae@tpd
  \egroup}
```

In otherwords, instead of having to test whether anything special has been done with `\parskip`, change the value locally.  But this does not have the desired effect at all when I've set `\parskip` to some nonzero value.  In the final product, the interline spacing seems to have inserted `2ex` of space between the end of the `minipage` and the following material, not at all what I wanted.

Now if I write something as inelegant as

```
\newcommand\restoretopreviousdepth{%%
  \bgroup
    \parskip0pt
    Hq
    \par\noindent 
    Hq
    \par\prevdepth\ae@tpd
  \egroup}
```

`\par` seems to be doing the right thing **except** when followed by `\prevdepth`.

Could someone explain what's happening here?

Comment: The `\parskip` is added when a horizontal command is scanned, that is, after `\egroup` has killed the setting of `\parskip=0pt`. It's not `\par` that adds `\parskip` glue.

Comment: why the `\newline` in `\end{minipage}%%'
\newline\restoretopreviousdepth` since `\restoretopreviousdepth` starts with `\par` that seems highly suspect.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The `\newline` was junk that I forgot I left in there when I posted the example here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The setting of `\parskip` in

```
\newcommand\restoretopreviousdepth{%%
  \bgroup
    \parskip0pt 
    \par\prevdepth\ae@tpd
  \egroup}
```

does nothing as `\parskip` is used when TeX *leaves* vertical mode to start a new paragraph, and that (if it happens at all) happens after the `\egroup` so the previous value will be used.

Comment: I blame the glass of wine I was having while reading the question, if I couldn't answer before you. +1

Comment: So this should work as I would like it to if I just add `\leavevmode` after `\prevdepth\ae@tpd` but before ending the group.  Right?  Ah but then my `\noindent` is ignored.  Sigh.

Comment: @egreg So you should accept that drinking wine is bad `;-)`

Comment: @HarishKumar Not at all! If it earns a tick to David, I can survive it.